# Find string by regular expression

Tags: regex

I need to make a regular expression to extract some strings.

The searching string could be like:

```
ANY_STRING(string1)this is
searching string1
ANY_STRING(string2)this is
searching string2
```

The match strings should be:

```
(string1)this is searching string1
(string2)this is searching string2
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: What language do you use for development?

Comment: How "any" is ANY_STRING? Would it be all caps and underscores? Might it contain parentheses? Spaces? Would the strings in the parens contain spaces or punctuation? The heart of regex success is knowing your data, which we don't and you might. Provide more details on that aspect and you'll get better results from answerers.

Comment: That is a very vague question. A correct answer for that single example you posted is: `(?<=\)).*\r?\n.*`

Answer (score 1):

Replace all newlines with space, then split the string with separator `ANY_STRING`.

Comment: The intention to use regular expression instead of some string functions is that I want to exploit the group function in regex afterward.

Comment: @zyq524: Please edit your question to show what grouping you need.

Answer (score 1):

assuming your strings to search are always between the brackets and assuming you are on *nix

```
$ awk '{match($0,/\(/);printf "%s ", substr($0,RSTART)} !/\(/{print ""}' file
(string1)this is searching string1
(string2)this is searching string2
```

Otherwise, you should provide more concrete data.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at interactive evaluators for regular expressions e.g. the one at [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm) (for Java syntax) or [rubular.com](http://rubular.com/) (Ruby syntax). Those might help you determine the expression you need.